# Getting javascript response from a PHP login function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, authentication

```
public function login($username,$password) {
    $linkingcon = $this->getConnection();
    $sqlquery = "SELECT ac.userID,ac.name,us.usertype FROM users us JOIN accounts ac ON us.userID = ac.userID WHERE us.username='$username' AND us.password='$password';";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlquery , $linkingcon);
    $this->throwMySQLExceptionOnError($linkingcon);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $survey = new stdClass();
    if($row) {
        $res->userID = (int)$row['userID'];
        $res->name = $row['name'];
        $res->usertype = (int)$row['usertype'];
                $string = rand() . 'SurveyLand' . rand() . $username. $password;
            $_SESSION['SURVEYLAND_KEY'] = md5($string);
    } else {
        $res = false;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Hi everyone,

im in a spot of bother regarding a conversion, I need to get a Javascript response from the above php function by calling that php function from another script(HTML)...

P.S
i saw an example in the internet like the below, cant i use method like below get the call

```
client.sendRequest('hello', null, { 'async': false }, function(rtn) {
    if (rtn.isError()) 
        document.write('<li>Request hello error: ' + rtn.getErrorMessage() + "</li>");
    else
        document.write('<li>Request hello result: ' + rtn.getResult() + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Use Ajax - print `$res` instead of returning it. In javascript send the request to this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ajax return response in json format

```
return json_encode($res);
```

Or just print response in script tag

```
<script>
   var res = <?php echo json_encode(login('username','password')); ?>
</script>
```